# Calulate distance between two points

Tags: distance, coordinates

If I have two coordinate points of (lat, lon), how would I calculate the distance between the two?

Comment: This has been answered in many dozens of threads here: please use our [search](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bdistance+%2Blat+%2Blon). It is also ambiguous: what software do you want to use, what accuracy do you need, what model of the earth will you assume?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) post goes into detail using a javascript script as an example.  The concept you want to look into is the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)